# How to convert a sympy decimal number to a Python decimal?

Tags: python

In sympy I can for example do:

```
from sympy import EulerGamma
EulerGamma.n(60)
0.577215664901532860606512090082402431042159335939923598805767
```

I would like to convert that into a Decimal number without losing any precision.

```
from decimal import Decimal as D
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100
D(EulerGamma.n(60))
TypeError: conversion from Float to Decimal is not supported
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing `D(str(EulerGamma.n(60)))`.  This will construct a `Decimal` from the object's string representation.